# How do i make wgnuplot.exe terminate at end of .plt file?

Tags: windows, gnuplot

I'm using gnuplot on Windows. When I execute my filename.plt-file directly via double clicking it spawns an instance of wgnuplot.exe, which doesn't terminate after finishing.

My code is very simple like this and just prints to a pdf.

Do any of you know how I can make wgnuplot.exe terminate automatically after finishing the file?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do also see this problem, tested with 4.6.5. Strangely it doesn't work to put an `exit` at the end of the file (typing `exit` in the `wgnuplot` shell closes it).

For me it works fine if I assiciate the `gnuplot.exe` binary instead of `wgnuplot.exe` with `.plt` files.