# Use gnuplot within Fortran code in Windows

Tags: windows, fortran, gnuplot

I have a fortran code as below

```
program compute_plot
  integer :: i, n = 10
  real :: x(10), y(10)

  x(1) = 0.0
  y(1) = 0.0

  do i = 2, n 
    x(i) = 0.1*i
    y(i) = x(i)*x(i)
  end do

  open(unit = 5, file = 'data.txt')
  do i = 1, n
    write(5,*) x(i),y(i)
  end do
  close(5)

  call system('gnuplot -p data_plot.gnu')
end program compute_plot
```

and another gnuplot script as below

```
reset
set terminal pngcairo dashed enhanced size 480,360 font 'arial,12' fontscale 1.0
set encoding utf8
set output 'plot.png'
set xlabel "x"
set ylabel "y"
m = "./data.txt"
set title 'The parabola'
plot m using 1:2 w l
```

These two code work well in Linux terminal, but I could not find a way to make them work in Windows command prompt. I also not sure if it is possible to make them work in Windows. Please advise.

Comment: If you open a command prompt on windows and type `gnuplot` do you start the gnuplot program or do you get something like a `'gnuplot is not recognized....` error?

Comment: Did you get any error message in Windows?

Comment: @d_1999 Yes, I did get `'gnuplot' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`.

Comment: You'll possibly want to add the path to the executable to your `PATH` environment variable (for example see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28545224) for how to do this on windows 7). You may want to use the command `wgnuplot` instead, if so you may find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24203126) helpful (which basically says don't as you may get some problems!).

Comment: @d_1999 Thank you so much. I added the directory of the executable `gnuplot.exe` to the `PATH` environment variables and the code work perfectly now.

Comment: @Kiat no problem. You might want to write a short answer explaining what you did to solve the problem so future visitors know how to fix this.

Comment: @d_1999 Certainly. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download gp503-win32-mingw.zip from [gnuplot](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/gnuplot/5.0.3/) official webpage;
2. Extract the zip file in your desired folder, e.g. `F:Document`;
3. The gnuplot folder will now have the path of `F:\Documents\gnuplot\`;
4. Right click `This PC`, click on `Properties`, click on `Advanced system settings`, click on `Advanced` tab, click on `Environment Variables...`;
5. Choose `Path` on the top table of `Environment Variables` windows, then click `Edit...`;
6. Now click on `New` to add in the path of `gnuplot.exe`, e.g. in my desktop `F:\Documents\gnuplot\bin`
7. To check if it is working properly, go to `Command prompt` and run the command of `gnuplot`.